# tmpfile_s() reads as empty even after fputs()

Tags: c, temporary-files, fputs

Here is a minimal example that does not do what I expected after the counsel of the user in comments to original question.  You can see the issue is not about `fflush()` because it is called after the `fputs()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    FILE *test_fileptr;
    int errorcode;
    
    errorcode = tmpfile_s(&test_fileptr);

    fputs("{}", test_fileptr);

    fflush(test_fileptr);
    rewind(test_fileptr);

    int c;
    int read_count = 0;
    
    char buffer[5] = "wxyz";

    while(read_count < 4) {
        c = fgetc(test_fileptr);
        if( feof(test_fileptr) ) {
            break;
        }
        buffer[read_count++] = c;
        printf("%c", c);
        printf(",%d", c);
    }
    printf("%s %d", "\ntmpfile return code was", errorcode);
    
    fclose(test_fileptr);
    
    return 0;
}
```

(The shape of solution attempted here is from the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64550508/1676499 )

I expect the fgetc to find the brace characters, but instead the output is these lines:

```
 ,-1 ,-1 ,-1 ,-1
tmpfile return code was 0
```

As a hint, I am entirely unable to get tmpfile() to return a FILE pointer, yet tmpfile_s() says it succeeds.  Why is that?

I can answer my own question now.  The problem is permissions.  Elevate the process running this code, and the temp file opens.  Though, this does not explain why `tmpfile_s()` doesn't return an error code:

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/tmpfile under 'Return Value' :

> "Zero if the file was created and open successfully, non-zero if the file was not created or open or if streamptr was a null pointer."

It didn't read from the file, so why did it return 0?

Comment: You should check the return value of `tmpfile_s` to see if it's successful.

Comment: Call `fflush(test_fileptr)` before `rewind`

Comment: After you changed the source, does the program now run as expected?

Comment: No, the output is as shown at the bottom, and I expect instead for it to read { and then } and then stop.